# How to declare array with existing arrays in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, dereference

So say I created a set of arrays like so:

```
my (@device, @mount, @type, @options, @dump, @pass) = ();
```

Then later I wanted to create an array with those arrays inside it.  How would I do that?  I tried to use:

```
my @columns = (@device, @mount, @type, @options, @dump, @pass);
```

and

```
my @columns = ([@device], [@mount], [@type], [@options], [@dump], [@pass]);
```

The issue seems to be that @columns remains empty.  I feel like I am making a really simple syntax mistake.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your second attempt does exactly what I thought you wanted: it produces an array that holds a copy of each of your original arrays. Please explain how that solution falls short of your produces so that we can help you further

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When you use, you just assign all values from given arrays to array `@columns`.

   ```
   my @columns = (@device, @mount, @type, @options, @dump, @pass);
   ```
2. Here, you just say all array by reference, if you use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) you can see structure of your array `@columns`.

   ```
   use Data::Dumper;

   my @columns = ([@device], [@mount], [@type], [@options], [@dump], [@pass]);
   print Dumper(\@columns);
   ```

You can do it using array references. Read this tutorial: [perlreftut - Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

```
my @columns = (\@device, \@mount, \@type, \@options, \@dump, \@pass);
```

Then use dereferencing:

```
my @new_device = @{ $columns[0] };
```

Comment: use `1.` not `1)` to denote a list.